# Looking for ways to speed up this Powershell script

Tags: multithreading, powershell

I've talked to Microsoft, they have said that they throttle the interface on their side but that if you run 7 jobs with 10,000 each, rather then one with 70,000, it should work fine because they only throttle each session individually.

I've streamlined the script itself using `Measure-Command` to get each section working at max speed, and got it working exactly how I want. 
So we're back to the original question now, somehow split the CSV input and run import jobs on each chunk, and also possibly do the same with the deleting and have multiple delete loops running simultaneously.

The two loops that need to be "multicasted" first, then the full updated script below:

Importing from CSV:

```
Do {
    $counter2 = 0
    $CSVpath = "C:\temp\testgal.csv"
    $contacts = Import-Csv "$CSVpath" 
    Measure-Command{
        foreach ($c in $contacts)  {
            Try {
                $ErrorActionPreference = "stop"
                $counter2++
                $name = $c.displayName
                $rawProxy = $c.proxyAddresses
                $proxysplit = $rawproxy -split '(?<!\\);'
                $proxyquoted = $proxysplit.replace('x500','"x500').replace('x400','"x400').replace('X500','"X500').replace('X400','"X400')
                $proxy = $proxyquoted
                Write-Progress -Activity 'Creating Contacts...' -CurrentOperation $c.displayName -PercentComplete (($counter2 / $contacts.Count) * 100)
                New-MailContact -ExternalEmailAddress $c.Mail -Name "`"$name`"" -Alias $c.mailNickname -DisplayName $name -FirstName $c.givenName -Initials $c.initials -LastName $c.sn
                Set-MailContact -Identity $c.mailNickname -CustomAttribute1 "CreatedWithScript" -CustomAttribute3 $c.extensionAttribute3 -EmailAddresses $proxy
                Set-Contact -Identity $c.mailNickname -City $c.l -Company $c.company -Department $c.department -Office $c.physicalDeliveryOfficeName `
                    -Phone $c.telephoneNumber -PostalCode $c.postalCode -Title $c.title
            }Catch {$_ | Out-File 'C:\temp\Error_Log.txt' -Append
                    Write-Warning -message "$name Already exists."}
        }
    }
Write-Progress -Activity "Creating Contacts..." -Status "Completed." -Completed
Write-Host "----------------------------------"
Write-Host "All Contacts successfully created."
Write-Host "----------------------------------"
$ErrorActionPreference = "continue"    
}
Until($? -eq "True")
```

Removing from 365:

```
Do{
$totalnumberremaining = Get-Mailcontact -Filter "CustomAttribute1 -eq 'CreatedWithScript'" -ResultSize unlimited
$numberremaining = Get-Mailcontact -Filter "CustomAttribute1 -eq 'CreatedWithScript'" -ResultSize 1000
$counter = 0
Do{
    foreach ($contact in $numberremaining) {
        $counter++
        Remove-MailContact -Identity $contact.Alias -Confirm:$False
    }
    Write-Progress -Activity 'Deleting Contacts...' -CurrentOperation $contact -PercentComplete (($counter / $totalnumberremaining.count) * 100)
}
Until($numberremaining -eq $null)
```

Full script:

```
#Logs into Office365
Do {
    $UserCredential = Get-Credential
    $Session = New-PSSession -ConfigurationName Microsoft.Exchange -ConnectionUri https://outlook.office365.com/powershell-liveid/ -Credential $UserCredential -Authentication Basic -AllowRedirection
    Import-PSSession $session
    Connect-MsolService -cred $UserCredential
}
Until ($? -eq "True")

Do{
#Removes all the current Contacts
$totalnumberremaining = Get-Mailcontact -Filter "CustomAttribute1 -eq 'CreatedWithScript'" -ResultSize unlimited
$numberremaining = Get-Mailcontact -Filter "CustomAttribute1 -eq 'CreatedWithScript'" -ResultSize 1000
$counter = 0
Do{
    foreach ($contact in $numberremaining) {
        $counter++
        Remove-MailContact -Identity $contact.Alias -Confirm:$False
    }
    Write-Progress -Activity 'Deleting Contacts...' -CurrentOperation $contact -PercentComplete (($counter / $totalnumberremaining.count) * 100)
}
Until($numberremaining -eq $null)
Write-Progress -Activity 'Deleting Contacts...' -Status "Completed." -Completed
Write-Host "----------------------------------"
Write-Host "All Contacts successfully removed."
Write-Host "----------------------------------"
Pause

# Imports new contacts from the CSV
Do {
    $counter2 = 0
    $CSVpath = "C:\temp\testgal.csv"
    $contacts = Import-Csv "$CSVpath" 
    Measure-Command{
        foreach ($c in $contacts)  {
            Try {
                $ErrorActionPreference = "stop"
                $counter2++
                $name = $c.displayName
                $rawProxy = $c.proxyAddresses
                $proxysplit = $rawproxy -split '(?<!\\);'
                $proxyquoted = $proxysplit.replace('x500','"x500').replace('x400','"x400').replace('X500','"X500').replace('X400','"X400')
                $proxy = $proxyquoted
                Write-Progress -Activity 'Creating Contacts...' -CurrentOperation $c.displayName -PercentComplete (($counter2 / $contacts.Count) * 100)
                New-MailContact -ExternalEmailAddress $c.Mail -Name "`"$name`"" -Alias $c.mailNickname -DisplayName $name -FirstName $c.givenName -Initials $c.initials -LastName $c.sn
                Set-MailContact -Identity $c.mailNickname -CustomAttribute1 "CreatedWithScript" -CustomAttribute3 $c.extensionAttribute3 -EmailAddresses $proxy
                Set-Contact -Identity $c.mailNickname -City $c.l -Company $c.company -Department $c.department -Office $c.physicalDeliveryOfficeName `
                    -Phone $c.telephoneNumber -PostalCode $c.postalCode -Title $c.title
            }Catch {$_ | Out-File 'C:\temp\Error_Log.txt' -Append
                    Write-Warning -message "$name Already exists."}
        }
    }
Write-Progress -Activity "Creating Contacts..." -Status "Completed." -Completed
Write-Host "----------------------------------"
Write-Host "All Contacts successfully created."
Write-Host "----------------------------------"
$ErrorActionPreference = "continue"    
}
Until($? -eq "True")

# Exits or repeats script on user imput
$response = read-host "Repeat(R) or Quit(Q)?"
}
While ($response -ne "Q")
Remove-PSSession $session
```

Comment: Have you done some benchmarks where the majority of your time is actually lost? From my experience the cmdlets concerning addresses are unfortunately rather slow. But still it would imho be wise to use some measure-object statements to make sure you are trying to optimize the right things. Also Write-Progess is (or at least was) pretty slow as far as I remember. And lastly did you check your memory consumtion? PS might gobble up all you RAM and then slow down to a total stall.

Comment: If you are going the workflow route, you would need to use `inlinescript` for `Get-MailContact`. But if you are only after parallelism, you could use [PoshRSJob](https://github.com/proxb/PoshRSJob) by Boe Prox

Comment: It's short term but at the moment we do have to wipe the table and repopulate, we're in the middle of an acquisition and the parent company hand us down these GAL lists weekly, people are removed changed and added to it, and I'm not sure how I could track those changes in it and only apply those?

Comment: You can of course use get-mailcontact and get-contact to create a list of all exisiting contacts and compare each imported contact to that list before you delete anything. But it is quite a bit of a hassle (I did the same thing just a short while ago for a smaller, local addressbook)

Comment: Once more thing: Would parallelization even increase the speed if you have only one endpoint to connect to? I really don't know this.

Comment: That's a good point whatever, I'm not sure how the endpoint would handle multiple streams coming into it.

Comment: Just to clarify, because I think it's a bit ambiguous, it's specifically the contents of the two foreach loops that I want to speed up I was looking into parallel stuff since if it was deleting say 2 or 4 contacts each run rather than one it would complete 2 to 4 times faster.So within the entire script I just want to speed up the two foreach loops, but each loop must be performed individually, so not to run both loops at the same time.